# Django template object return empty value

Tags: django, django-templates, django-database

I filter a subject from database:

subject = Subject.objects.filter(id=1)

I tried to call it form template:

```
 {{ subject.name|safe }}
```

It return empty value. Do I need to loop the object? It just return a single records:

```
>>> subject[0].name
u'010-01 INTERNATIONAL : Organizations'
```

But when I put {{  subject[0].name|safe }}, it return no value too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:
`{{subject.0.name}}`

If you're only getting one object from the database, you should typically use

```
try:
    subject = Subject.objects.get(id=1)
except Subject.DoesNotExist:
    pass #do whatever handling stuff you need to do here
```

You could also use the [get_object_or_404](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/?from=olddocs#a-shortcut-get-object-or-404) shortcut.